# Ubuntu 22.04 Wi-Fi getting super slow after some time

Tags: networking, internet, download-speed

I have a PC running Ubuntu 22.04 connected via Wi-Fi. I have the network usage meter live in the top right corner of the screen, so I can monitor the speed on real time (besides my experience while browsing and using the internet connection). For some reason, after some time of usage, usually between 10 and 60 minutes, the connection gets (and remains forever) super slow, such that the download speed never gets higher than 180 KB/s, when normally it should go up to about 5 MB/s. I noticed that when this happens, it gets fixed if I go into airplane mode and back into non-airplane mode. After some time, between 10 and 60 minutes, the cycle starts over.

Though this is a solution for web browsing, usually I am using a VPN with several applications running and it is awkward to have to restart everything periodically.

What could it be the problem?

The output of `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'` is `wlp2s0: mtu 1500`.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show me the command (and results) of: `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check how full your VPN server is. I've noticed when a Proton server exceeds 25% full, my download speeds dip into kbs/second. Try switching to a less populated VPN server, and see if that does the trick.

For example, when downloading a Kali Linux .iso, I dipped into kbs/second; my server was at 26% full. I switched to a 10% full server, and my speeds returned to mbs/second.

As for your output, refer to this answer(to another question, but it explains your terminal output): https://askubuntu.com/a/723182/1754795

MTU = Maximum Transmission Unit
See this TechTarget article for more information. If your output was 1500, I'm guessing you were using an ethernet cable. | https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/maximum-transmission-unit